# Adding Blazor module to ABP solution

Tags: angular, blazor, abp

I already have an existing ABP solution with Angular as the front end and I want to add a Blazor front end.
The Blazor app should not be depend on the Angular front end, and as the Angular app it should support all the ABP account features, like login, register, etc.

Is it possible? How to?

Answer (score 0):

There is not any ABP CLI command to automatically create and add a blazor project and add it to your solution automatically.

I think the easiest way to add a new Blazor application to your application is creating a new blazor application via ABP CLI (with the command `abp new YourProjectName --ui blazor`) and then move it to your solution and make the related changes.

For example, you can check the following steps which are came to my mind instantly:

- Change the `appsettings.json` file in the Blazor project after moving it to your own solution. (Authority should be changed for instance)
- Add the Blazor Client in the data seed contributor class in the domain layer.
- Update the `appsettings.json` file in dbmigrator project etc...